# React Native and In-App Purchase?

Tags: in-app-purchase, react-native

I have to build an app for iOS and Android and I was thinking about using React Native to do the job, but I don't find anything regarding In-App Purchase. Do you know any existing solution for adding In-App Purchase to both the iOS and Android version without too much headache?

Comment: I've created a Product Pains request for this to be added to React Native: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/support-for-in-app-purchases

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am the author of an InApp Billing library for RN on Android; [react-native-billing](https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing).

I've been considering also supporting iOS from the same library, but it would require a substantial rewrite since there is some difference in feature-parity. Also the API behaves in different ways.

For now, if you need iOS support as well, I'd use [react-native-in-app-utils](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils).

Comment: Does this support renewable subscription ?

Comment: @SoorajChandran yes it has support for renewable subscription as well. Check documentation for **Monthly Subscriptions** where you install  [receipt-validator](https://github.com/sibelius/iap-receipt-validator) Library  for Subscriptions.

Comment: The iOS package mentioned above seems to be not well maintained anymore.
For a package that is recent and handles both iOS and Android check out  https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap

Answer (score 9):

[react-native-in-app-utils](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-in-app-utils) works nicely with iOS. As for Android there isn't anything yet, though I am working on a PR in my spare time to provide this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is something that uses stripe apple pay and android pay - https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

It might be what expo uses internally, I'm not sure.

Here is another that seems promising - https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments - it seems to use native GUI everywhere even in browser, I am going to try this one, I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of 3rd party components out there (much more for iOS as its early days for Android) but if you can't find what you want then it would be a matter of writing the in app purchase code in native for iOS and android then bridging to the react-native JS side with your own react-native component.

Comment: Please check this link if will work for both iOS and android 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-iap